Question about Vector Spaces
I am relatively new to linear algebra and I got a goofy question. In my textbook, it defines $R^n$ as the set of all ordered lists of length n (n-tuples) of real numbers. I wanted to ask that supposing that we have $R^3$, an ordered pair, say $(x, y)$, would not be in $R^3$. In other words, that $(x, y) \in R^3$ would be false, it would be have to be written as $(x, y, 0) \in R^3$ to be true.
Thanks for your time!

This is correct.
